# const_iterator Prolems

Tags: visual-c++

I've never used const_iterator before and am having difficulty getting this to debug.  Any help is appreciated. Windows 7 and VS 2010  Thank you.

```
typedef std::basic_string <unsigned char> ustring;
ustring receivedData(data[i], length);
typedef std::map<string, int> MapMime;
MapMime mymap;

mymap["audio/basic"] = 1;
mymap["audio/x-aiff"] = 2;
mymap["audio/x-wav"] = 3;
mymap["video/mpeg"] = 4;
mymap["video/mpeg-2"] = 5;
mymap["video/quicktime"] = 6;

for (MapMime::const_iterator it = mymap.begin(), itEnd = mymap.end();it !=   itEnd.++it);
{
size_t findPosition = receivedData.find(it->first);
if (findPosition != string::npos)
    {
    // Found a match at position findPosition
    }
    else
    {
    // That MIME type was not found in the data...
    }
}
```

Comment: So, what isn't working for you?  You've got a `.` instead of a semicolon `;` in your for control expression, otherwise it looks fine.

Comment: Thank you, that helped.  I'm still getting an error that "it" is undefined on the size_t line. As well as this....Error 2 error C2227: left of '->first' must point to class/struct/union/generic type

Answer (score 3):

You have an extra semicolon after the for loop, you should remove it. Otherwise, 'it' is defined only inside the for loop, which is empty.

Comment: ... and neither of the errors had anything to do with `const_iterator`.

Comment: I removed it != itEnd;++it)  Now I'm getting an error on the receivedData.find    Error 1 error C2664: 'unsigned int std::basic_string<_Elem>::find(const std::basic_string<_Elem> &,unsigned int) const' : cannot convert parameter 1 from 'const std::string' to 'const std::basic_string<_Elem> &'  AND   2 IntelliSense: no instance of overloaded function "std::basic_string<_Elem, _Traits, _Ax>::find [with _Elem=unsigned char, _Traits=std::char_traits<unsigned char>, _Ax=std::allocator<unsigned char>]" matches the argument list The proverbial can of worms have been opened!

Comment: Why do you even need ustring? I.e. what's wrong with defining receivedData to be string? I'm assuming string is a typedef for std::string.

Comment: The problem is data is an unsigned char and is not part of basic string.

Comment: Try to typecast data[i] to (char*) and use the std::string constructor. It seems you have to convert unsigned char to char at some point anyway.